# Finetune LLM model on tabular data

Tags: csv, finetuning, data-table, llm

Is it possible or even recommended to finetune LLMs such as llama2 on tabular data?

I have a csv with historical gold buy prices.

```
DAY,HOUR,OPEN,HIGH,LOW,CLOSE,VOLUME
2018.06.28,03:02,1.15603,1.15613,1.15602,1.15605,107
```

I'm hoping to be able to ask a question like what was the volume on 2018.06.28 or what date had the most volume ect.

Thanks in advance.